# Sum $total in Loop PHP when mssql_query("COMMIT") success insert data to database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, php-mssql

I'm trying to "sum" `$total` in loop.

This is the full code:

```
foreach ( $array_permall as $perm ) {
    if($lastcheck != "1" && $checkoutlet != 1){
        //izin gagal
        echo "2";
        exit();
    }else{
        $total = 0;
        $sqlIns = "BEGIN TRAN ";

        if($lastcheck == "1"){
            $sqlIns .=  "INSERT INTO T_Absen_Permission (NIK,Reason,Date,AddBy,AddDate) VALUES('".$nik."','PERMISSION ALL','".$tglco."','".$User."',getdate());";

            $sqlIns .=  "INSERT INTO T_Absen Values('".$nik."','".$long."','".$lat."','".$rid."','".$oid."','CHECK OUT','".$tglco."','PERMISSION By ".$User."');";
        }

        if($checkoutlet == 1){
            $sqlIns .=  "INSERT INTO T_Absen_Permission (NIK,Reason,Date,AddBy,AddDate,Note) VALUES('".$nik."','PERMISSION ALL',dbo.GetLastDay(getdate(),'".$nik."'),'".$User."',getdate(),'Permission Outlet');";
        }

        if(mssql_query($sqlIns)){
            mssql_query("COMMIT");
            $total++;
        }else{
            mssql_query("ROLLBACK");
            echo "5";
        }
    }
    echo $total;
}
```

But the result is always 11111. I want the result is like : 1+1+1+1+1 = **5**

I want use Final Result **5** to make alert in JavaScript.

How can I do it with PHP?

Comment: Thats nothing to do with SQL Server - somehow your `$total` is ending up as a string...

Comment: Use `int($total++);` to parse as number

Comment: Can't use int($total++);
Here the message error :
Fatal error: Call to undefined function int()

Comment: try $total=(int)$total+1; instead of $total++;

Comment: or check the place where you initialised $total before this foreach

Comment: $total=(int)$total+1; instead of $total++; Cannot use this too, the result is like this 2468101214

Comment: i never initialised $total before foreach

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration you're setting `$total = 0` so after each iteration and `$total++;` it gets incremented to `1` that's why you are getting `1` echoed each time loop runs, Initialize your `$total=0` variable outside the loop, Hope it helps.